# Verify if the current page has at least one published child

Tags: page-template, child-pages

In my theme php page template, I need to echo a string only if the page has at least one published child page. Actually, I have a function that verifies if the current page has any children, regardless of their status (see code below). But I can't figure how to go further with this function to either:

- Echo my string only if the current page has at least one PUBLISHED child page

OR

- Don't echo my string if the current page has no PUBLISHED child page.

Thank you in advance.

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
);

$children = get_children( $args );

if ( ! empty($children) ) {
    echo 'My string');
}
```

Comment: `get_children` may not work how you think it does, but like most other backwards compat functions you're better off cutting out the wrappers and going straight for the original function instead of wrappers that add unexpected behaviour, use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` instead

Comment: the docu https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_children/ implies that you can set 'post_status' in the $args

Comment: Thanks Tom and Micheal. I'm still not fluent with PHP. Would someone demonstrate a code example for me, using get_posts or WP_Query ? thank you in advance.